# How can I fix the footer at the bottom of a div with "position:absolute"?

Tags: html, css

How can I fix this "popup-footer" at the bottom of the "inner" div?

```css
.inner {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div className="inner">
    <div className="popup-header">
         UPDATE
    </div>
    <div className="popup-body">

    </div>
    <div className="popup-footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

PS: I want to mention that the "inner" div have the position set to `absolute`. I didn't found any solutions for this .. not even with bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add to your footer element `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`, this will fix it. Child `absolute` element will have position, relative to it's parent `absolute` element, not a viewport.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative; 
}
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; 
}
.popup-footer {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; /* this will fix it */
  left: 0; /* and fixing to a left side */
  /* just to see it */
  background: #aaa; 
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
    <div class="popup-header">
         UPDATE
    </div>
    <div class="popup-body">

    </div>
    <div class="popup-footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when you define your classes names, make sure you use `class=` instead of `className=`

Try this:

```
<div class="inner">
        <div class="popup-header">
             HEADER
        </div>
        <div class="popup-body">
             BODY
        </div>
        <div class="popup-footer">
             FOOTER
        </div>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.inner {
 position: absolute;
 height:100%;
}
.popup-footer{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Nice try. But `position:fixed;` will fix it not inside an `.inner`, but inside a viewport. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: You're quite right  @focus.style, perhaps a better solution is having `absolute` instead of `fixed`.

Comment: `className` may be correct. It indicates the asker is using a front-end framework like react which uses the `className` attribute for css classes.